# Pyspark Dataframe to S3 Parquet file error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to write spark dataframe to S3 in parquet format using below code. but it fails with below error :

23/05/08 16:32:58 WARN MultiObjectDeleteSupport: Bulk delete operation failed to delete all objects; failure count = 1
23/05/08 16:32:58 WARN MultiObjectDeleteSupport: AccessDenied: sparkbyexamples/: Access Denied
3/05/08 16:33:00 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 87b0-769a9f063507.
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for s3ablock-0001-
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:462) ~[hadoop-client-api-3.3.3-amzn-2.jar:?]

Code used:

```
spark_df.write.parquet("s3a://sparkbyexamples/parquet/people.parquet")
```

I have read access on sparkbyexamples folder and write access on subfolder parquet. I was able to write CSV files to this path using boto3. Why am I getting access error on parent folder? I am trying to write into subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

two errors here.

`org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException`: no temp dir to buffer blocks being written. Make sure you have set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir` to a path in your local fs where there's space.

For the delete, it's because when a file is created it sends a DELETE up above it to get rid of any spurious / directory markers.

- it's just a warn not an error (maybe it should only warn once, FWIW)
- you can turn off the marker deletion with

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.marker.retention keep
```

this is good to do to save on IO and on versioned buckets, tombstone markers. Now the feature has been out for a while it should be turned on by default. The sole reason it's not done already is it isn't backwards compatible with older releases trying to write to same directories (rename and delete, specifically)